# Grouping a column, and then subtracting rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have had a look at other questions but still struggled with this so I thought I would put it up.

I Need to produce a list of all the outstanding orders, and order by part.

So columns I have are Partid, tradequantity, and invoicequantity.

So trader quantity is the quantity that has been ordered, and invoice is quantity that has been delivered.

I kind have got halfway through...but I got a feeling I may need a new table? here is the code so far.

```
select (traderquantity - invoicedquantity) AS balance, partid, invoicedquantity,traderquantity
from orderitems  
where status = 'ACTIVE'
and ordertype = 'PO'
order by partid
```

Initially tried using Sum on traderquantity and subtract InvoiceQuanity, but when I go to group by PartId it returns an error.

EDIT: just to add I can actually finish this using Excel but I would like to know how to do this in SQL.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    SUM(traderquantity - invoicedquantity) AS balance, 
    partid, 
    SUM(invoicedquantity) AS TotalInvoicedquantity,
    SUM(traderquantity) AS TotalTraderquantity
from 
    orderitems  
where 
    status = 'ACTIVE'
    and ordertype = 'PO'
GROUP BY 
    partid
order by 
    partid
```

Comment: You're a star! Thank you very much. Think I better get a SQL dummies guide!

Comment: Thought I would add I was halfway there with other attempts. I had the first line as above with the subtraction within the brackets, but didn't think to SUM the other columns. Makes perfect sense now looking at it!